# 2 Way SSL Performance Impact

Tags: ssl

By enabling 2Way SSL (both inbound and outbound), is there a performance impact / overhead (over 1 Way), specially for large volume data transactions.

My understanding is that only a few kilobytes of client certificate shared during the initial handshake should not cause any significant performance overhead on the overall integration.

Any thoughts / evidences appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mutual authentication (two-way SSL), both ends authenticate the other, rather than just one side authenticating the other. This all happens in the handshake, and therefore only affects initial startup time. Once both sides are authenticated, the connection switches from the slower asynchronous encryption method to a faster synchronous encryption method, which is how the bulk of the data is transferred. The difference in startup time should be on the order of milliseconds, hardly anything worth worrying over. If you need the extra security feature, two-way SSL is recommended.